# Shell: Check line format file and loop over file lines

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I need to check 2 assetions:

1. The file content format
2. Iterate over that content:

So, the content file must be:

```
key1=value
key2=value2
...
```

So, each line must have the format `key=value`. Spaces are not allowed before or after the `=`. This file content has to be an env format file.

By other hand, I need to split out each line into a `key` and a `value` inside a loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the restrictions on the key and value? Single words? Are quoted strings ok? Are multi-line value ok? Are values containing `=` ok?

Comment: Only has to match `<word>=<word>`

Comment: Right, but can a "word" be `preference=apple-juice` for a valid line reading `drink=preference=apple-juice`?  Are spaces allowed before and/or after the `=`?

Comment: No. This file content has to be an env format file.

Comment: Do you mean that `key1=value with spaces` should be rejected, or that it should be parsed as key=`key1` and value=`value with spaces`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash:

```
n=0
while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
    ((n++))
    if [[ -z $key ]]; then echo "missing key on line $n"; continue; fi
    if [[ -z $value ]]; then echo "empty value on line $n"; continue; fi
    echo "key:>$key<; value:>$value<"
done <<END
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=
=value3
foo

key4=value4=value5=value6
END
```

outputs

```
key:>key1<; value:>value1<
key:>key2<; value:>value2<
empty value on line 3
missing key on line 4
empty value on line 5
missing key on line 6
key:>key4<; value:>value4=value5=value6<
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this file as `input`:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=
=value3
key4=value4
```

We can use `=` as a field separator for `awk`:

```
$ awk -F= '!($1 && $2 && NF==2) { print "File failed validation on line " NR; exit 1} { print $1, $2 }' input
key1 value1
key2 value2
File failed validation on line 3
```

To throw validation error messages to standard error, the `print` statement can be modified, and to continue processing after an error is seen, change the `exit` statement to a `next` statement:

```
$ awk -F= '!($1 && $2 && NF==2) { print "File failed validation on line " NR | "cat 1>&2"; next } { print $1, $2 }' input
[stdout] key1 value1
[stdout] key2 value2
[stdout] key4 value4
[stderr] File failed validation on line 3
[stderr] File failed validation on line 4
```

Validation is done in three steps; if any of these criteria are not met the error is thrown and, in the first example, execution is aborted with an error-state exit code:

- `$1` - Ensure that there is (in the parlance of the input specification) a "key"
- `$2` - Ensure that there is (in the parlance of the input specification) a "value"
- `NF==2` - Ensure that there are only two fields; the aforementioned "key" and "value"